Indexeddb - records are added successfully, except index is missing data
Using indexeddb and idb promise library.
I have this objectstore that I create called storeMappings along with the index inUse. I then populate the store with some records.
Everything works as it should except for one issue. The index inUse does not show any data. Any ideas why?
const _addStoreMappings = async (db) => {
  const mappings = db.createObjectStore('storeMappings', {                            
    keyPath: 'id', 
    autoIncrement: true,                                                              
  });                                                                                 
  
  await mappings.createIndex('inUse', 'inUse');                                       
  
  await mappings.add({ store: `store0`, name: `foo store`, inUse: true });            
  
  Array.fromAsync({ length: 14 }, (_, i) => (
    mappings.add({ store: `store${++i}`, name: '', inUse: false })                    
  ));                                                                                 
};  




I had the same issue and could solve it by changing the type of index property from bool to string.
This should work:
await mappings.add({ store: 'store0', name: 'foo store', inUse: 'true' });
